# Why does Caps Lock not change symbol keys?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I've never thought about this before, but why have a `Caps Lock` instead of a `Shift Lock`? Is there historical context for this?

Though my muscle memory knows to expect different functionality from turning on `Caps Lock` than from holding down `Shift`, it seems to make logical sense that a key like `Caps Lock` should also force the `9` key to output a `(` instead of a `9`.

Why is `Caps Lock` not the equivalent of `Shift Lock`?

Note: Answers of `Because it's called Caps Lock` are not what I'm looking for.
Not that it matters, but I'm using a QWERTY layout on a US-based code page.

Comment: Quoting [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caps_lock#History): "*Some early computer keyboards, such as the Commodore 64, had a Shift lock but no Caps Lock; others, such as the BBC Micro, had both, only one of which could be enabled at a time. [ ] A version of Caps Lock that behaves like a traditional Shift lock does exist on certain layouts such as the French AZERTY.*" The question is just asking for opinions. Think: which would be more common - to type numbers along capital letters or to type `#$%&` along capital letters. The more common/convenient option prevails.

Comment: Hope you see my comment: on azerty keyboard (france) the caps lock is a shift lock like you are describing. This is because we have the numbers as secondary and symbol as primary aka to get numbers we have to use the shift key OR the caps lock which as I said works like a shift lock.